# Error CS0308 while trying to learn how to use Span in C#

Tags: c#

i'm trying to learn how to use Span in C# and there's an example in the book that doens't work in my project.

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Span<int> span1 = arr1;
```

The error is the following "CS0308 C# The non-generic type cannot be used with type arguments"

Comment: What .net version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that you are using a .netFramework console app. You will need to create a .net Core console app in order to use Span.

Eg:

[image]

Comment: It was easier than i thought, thank you very much!